# Advanced multi-conditonal split with an regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to split a string on multiple conditions such as:

- After each `/;/`
- After each `/{/` or `/}/`
- After each `/\w+:/` but not after `/\w+:\s+\{/`
- After each `/#\w.*$/`

I've found that I can keep a pattern and split before it with

```
/(?=pattern)/
```

or split after it (if the pattern has a fixed width)

```
/(?<=pattern)/
```

or split after it (if the pattern has a variable width)

```
/pattern\K/
```

or even remove the pattern during the operation

```
/pattern/
```

With all this knowledge I wrote this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl    
$_ = do { local $/; <DATA> };
s/\#\w.+\n\K|\n//g;

my @content = split /(?:(?<=[;{}])|(?<=:)(?!\s*\{)|#\w.*\$\K)/, $_;

print join "\n", @content;

__DATA__
carrot;
#orange
apple: {pear; { cabbage; } }
#passion
sprout: celeri;
tomato;
```

Where the output should be this (after manually reindenting it):

> ```
> carrot;
> #orange
> apple: {
>   pear;
>   {
>     cabbage;
>   }
> }
> #passion
> sprout:
> celeri;
> tomato;
> ```

I am not really happy with this method for multiple reasons:

- I cannot use a `x` regex in split like `split m/re/x` to make the regex more readable
- I need to treat the exception for the special case `/^\s*#.*$/` where I cannot remove CR otherwise I will get for instance `#passionsprout:`

Can I do a better job?

Comment: Perhaps https://eval.in/388671

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think the other way around: try to add a newline to all characters that need one. That way your regex is a bit simpler.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $content = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $regex = qr{
  (?m)
    (^
     |
     :\s*
    )
    \{                  # open curly brace preceded by 
                        # beginning of line
                        # OR
                        # colon

  |                     # OR
    [:;\}]              # any of these characters
    (?!\s*\n)           # NOT followed by newline
}x;

$content =~ s/($regex)/$1\n/g;
print $content, "\n";
```